# System.getProperty("plugins.dir") return null

Tags: java, imagej, fiji

I am trying to run imageJ project in eclipse but while running the project i am getting "null" value while printing this "System.getProperty("plugins.dir")" in my console, i already included imageJ jar(ij.jar) but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to pass this property using -Dplugins.dir notation during the start of your application.